# Shipping method - number of products flat rate

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipping, shipping-methods

Hello I've found the way to implement shipping method for multiple products. I have created a new module and wrote the code to implement ( fore every four products add shipping cost of 2.99).When I insert the code into the module I cant proceed to the Shipping methods in the checkout it just loads for two seconds and stops. Could anyone spot the problem in my code ?

```
    protected $_code = 'shipping_mycarrier';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
            return false;
        }
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $reminder = 4;
        $defprice = 2.99;
        $products = $request->getAllItems();
        $noproducts = count($products);
        $price = ($noproducts / $reminder) * $defprice;

        $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $rate->setMethod($this->_code);
        $rate->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $rate->setPrice($price);
        $rate->setCost(0);

       return $rate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried table-rates shipping method in "# of items vs. destination" mode ?

Comment: I thought of doing that but it would take to long writing it all up for each country in the csv file . Also I've tried different generators for that but they don't work this way unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, you'll either have to search for some extension that has this feature or build a custom shipping method yourself with this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that additional method `_getStandardShippingRate()` in your class. In fact, if it's get called, it will trigger an infinite recursion in your code. Without that method, your class should look like this :

```
<?php
    class Shipping_MyCarrier_Model_Carrier extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface {

        protected $_code = 'shipping_mycarrier';

        public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
            if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
                return false;
            }
            $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
            $reminder = 4;
            $defprice = 2.99;
            $products = $request->getAllItems();
            $noproducts = count($products);
            $price = ($products / $reminder) * $defprice;

            $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
            $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $rate->setMethod($this->_code);
            $rate->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $rate->setPrice($price);
            $rate->setCost($price);
            $result->append($rate);
            return $result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Still when I try to load the next step it just loads for 2 seconds and stops no difference.

Comment: See in your console, if there is any error returned with the request. If not, then also consult with your log files and add that information in the question here.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img905/1524/kPuKxK.png This is what I get. every time it posts savebilling and getadditional but doesn't return anything back + post doesn't disapear as you can see on the screen shot. I've clicked it multiple times and it just repeats.

Comment: These are ajax requests. You'll need to see their response by clicking on them. Better would be to check your log files, if there is anything related in there.